# How can I determine the type of the critical point?

Tags: calculus

I have to determine the type of critical points of the function: 
$$f(x, y, z)=x^2+y^2+z^2+xy$$

I have done the following:

$$\nabla f=(2x+y, 2y+x, 2z) \\ \nabla f=0 \Rightarrow \\ 2x+y=0 \Rightarrow y=-2x \\ 2y+x=0 \Rightarrow 2(-2x)+x=0 \Rightarrow -4x+x=0 \Rightarrow -3x=0 \Rightarrow x=0 \\ 2z=0 \Rightarrow z=0$$

So, the only critical point of $f$ is the point $(0, 0, 0)$.

Is this correct so far??

How can I determine the type of the critical point, if it is a local maxima or a local minima??

$$$$

**EDIT:**

$$f(x, y, z)=x^2+y^2+z^2+xy \\ =\frac{1}{2}x^2+xy+\frac{1}{2}y^2+z^2+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{2}y^2 \\ =\frac{1}{2}(x^2+2xy+y^2)+z^2+\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2) \\ =\frac{1}{2}(x+y)^2+z^2+\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2) \geq 0$$

Comment: multiply the function by $4$ and complete some squares

Comment: In more general case https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix may be used

Comment: each  of the coefficients of the square are positive and therefore we must have a minimum because the function tend to $\infty$ where the variables are large.

Comment: Could you take a look at the edit part of my initial post?? Do we have to write it in that way?? @WillJagy

Comment: you left off a $1/2$ in the final line

Comment: Oh yes, I added it ... Is it correct now?? @WillJagy

Comment: yes.  As Alexey pointed out, you get the same result by finding the Hessian matrix (of second partial derivatives) and confirming that it is positive definite. For this one, the eigenvalues are easy enough, in general one uses Sylvester's criterion using principal minors to avoid finding actual eigenvalues. The treatment in your book may or may not include the name Sylvester.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. One way of determinig the critical point is by completing the square. Since the terms are positive you must have a local minimum(in this case a global minimum). Another way is to examine the determinant of the second derivative. If it is +, the you have a minimum. - is a local maximum...

Comment: Could you take a look at the edit part of my initial post?? Do we have to write it in that way??

Answer (score 0):

More generally, you can assess the type of critical point by examining the second order partial derivatives.  You may want to read up on eigenvalues of the Hessian matrix.

Answer (score 0):

The Hessian of the objective function = [2 2 0;2 2 0;0 0 2] regardless of x,y,z.. This is positive semi-definite (psd) everywhere, so the objective function and optimization problem is convex, (in particular, the Hessian is  psd at the point (0,0,0)). Therefore the critical point is indeed not only a local minimum, but due to convexity of the optimization problem, a global minimum.  Because the Hessian is only positive semi-definite and not positive definite, examination of the Hessian is not sufficient to conclude that the candidate point is the unique global minimum. But because it is the only point satisfying the first order optimality conditions that gradient = vector of zeros, it must indeed be the unique global minimizer.

The completing the square approach may work in this case, but the approach I've described is more general, and applies even when the objective function is not quadratic.  If the problem is constrained, then you need to look at Karush-Kuhn Tucker conditions (which amounts to the gradient projected into the nullspace of the Jacobian of active constraints being the vector of zeros, with the Lagrange multipliers of active inequalities having the correct sign) and need the Hessian of the Lagrangian projected into the nullspace of the Jacobian of active constraints to be positive semi-definite for a local minimum (and positive definite to guarantee a global minimum).  In the unconstrained case, there are no active constraints (or inactive constraints either for that matter), so the projected gradient and projected Hessian are just the gradient and Hessian respectively, and this reduces to the more familiar conditions described earlier.